# Can't connect to localhost on Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I got this error suddenly.
Before getting this error I could connect.

```
$ curl localhost:3000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused
```

My environments are below.

OS：macOS Sierra 10.12.6
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build: web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - "DATABASE_HOST=db"
      - "DATABASE_PORT=5432"
      - "DATABASE_USER=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
      - "DATABASE_PASSWORD=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app" #共有フォルダの設定
    stdin_open: true

  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_USER=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.0

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client
RUN gem install rails
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
```

If you have some suggestion to solve this please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Based on your Dockerfile, you shouldn't be able to start your `web` container since it doesn't specify an `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`

Comment: Thank you for your response.Usually I run the web by using docker run command.Is it fault?

Answer (score 2):

you should specify your command for running application like: `bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'` which run your server on port `3000` and bind it to local network `0.0.0.0`.
so you should write it in your `Dockerfile` in the last line:

```
RUN bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
```